# java - Error Internal Server Error” in blueimp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2

In `blueimp` JQuery fileupload the backend I am using is `struts 2`.
         I want to send reponse image preview. Am getting image name and size except the image preview and href.

```
Fire bug:

    <a href="" title="Photo-0010.jpg" download="Photo-0010.jpg">Photo-0010.jpg</a>
    <span class="size">310.12 KB</span>
```

I am not doing anything to get the title of the image, just getting the files and uploading in a path in action class. I don't know where its getting the name of the image but why not the `href` link. I tried to display using

```
    <img src="<s:property value="filesFileName"/>"/>
```

but its not working.
    It is going to

```
 "// Callback for failed (abort or error) uploads:
fail: function (e, data) " in jquery.fileupload-ui.js

I want to display the image preview and `href`.
Can anyone help?
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Am doing nothing more in action for image name, size or other. Just coping in server.String filePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, filesFileName.get(i)); FileUtils.copyFile(files.get(i), fileToCreate);

Comment: This the code from jquery.fileupload-ui.js But i don know where they are getting href and other properties. If i did alert in name its giving image name and href its showing my localhost url. _enableDragToDesktop: function () { var link = $(this), url = link.prop('href'), name = link.prop('download'), type = 'application/octet-stream';alert(url); link.bind('dragstart', function (e) { try { e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData( 'DownloadURL', [type, name, url].join(':') ); } catch (ignore) {} }); },

Comment: "// Callback for failed (abort or error) uploads:
fail: function (e, data) " in jquery.fileupload-ui.js